# kendo ui datepicker no style

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I've been using kendo ui for asp.net mvc 3 and I'm having some problems whit datepickers
the problem is that my datepickers renders a simple input date instead od the gorgeous controls

here is my code

```
<table class="table-container">
    <tr>
         </td>
         <td class="item-value">
            @(Html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(model => model.paymentDueDate)
              .Name("datepicker")
              .Value(DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString())
              .HtmlAttributes(new { type = "text" })
            )
    </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

and in the header the next

```
<link media="screen" type="text/css" href="/kendo/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link media="screen" type="text/css" href="/kendo/styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link media="screen" type="text/css" href="/kendo/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/kendo.datepicker.min.js">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/kendo.web.min.js">
```

I also added the reference to kendo.Mvc.dll

and that renders a simple input date
here is the code I got in firefox after running the application

```
<input id="datepicker" type="text" value="11/07/2013" name="datepicker" class="valid">
```

I havent found anything  about that

am I missing some css or js?

please help this is getting me crazy

thanks in advance

Comment: have you tried just as simple html and not as helper

Comment: Hi! what namespaces/NuGet packages are you using here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you including jQuery? Before any other JS you should include jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery.min.js">
```

Comment: Actually I did included jquery.js but what was really causing this it's that the jquery script was positioned under the other script tags. I just move to the top and works like a charm
thank you so much @OnaBai, you save my day.

Comment: You're welcome. Since you're new here, please don't forget to mark the answer accepted which helped most in solving the problem. See also [How does accepting an answer work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/202683)?